# How to access current user in admin.py

Tags: django

In my admin.py file I am trying to display a time as the logged in users timezone. If I have something like below how can I pass in the request also to access the request.user.userprofile so I can dynamically set the timezone?

```
class CapAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
list_display = ('time_clicked', 'source_name', 'link')
....

    def time_clicked(self, instance):
        local_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago') # I want the user timezone here
        local_dt = instance.click_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz)
        return mark_safe("{0}").format(local_tz.normalize(local_dt).strftime('%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p'))
```

Comment: What class is this code part of? What is calling it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry I updated my post. It is a part of a CapAdmin class and is being called in the list_display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the user there. But you don't need it; you should be activating the timezone in middleware, as described in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone). Something like:

```
class TimezoneMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.timezone
            tzname = request.user.timezone
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
```

Add this to your middleware settings. Now in your admin class you can do:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

def time_clicked(self, instance):
    return localtime(instance.time_clicked)
```